# how can i get specific value from xml by another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```html
<dataset>
<study recNO="0" seriesRecCount="1">
      <patientID>123456</patientID>
      <accessionNumber>M120170428105320</accessionNumber>
      <patientIDID>35</patientIDID>
      <studyUID>2.25.143966910120672170538921915162328371094</studyUID>
      <studyUIDID>251</studyUIDID>
</study>
<study recNO="1" seriesRecCount="1">
      <patientID>123456</patientID>
      <accessionNumber>M120170428105233</accessionNumber>
      <patientIDID>35</patientIDID>
      <studyUID>2.25.303229748643803883750255516818503774905</studyUID>
      <studyUIDID>252</studyUIDID>
</study>
</dataset>
```

I get **accessionNumber** from url query string.
I want to get **studyUID** by using **accessionNumber** 
How can i do by using jQuery?

Thank you very much

Comment: the famous question: have you tied anything ?

Comment: see this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var xml = $('<dataset><study recNO="0" seriesRecCount="1"><patientID>123456</patientID><accessionNumber>M120170428105320</accessionNumber><patientIDID>35</patientIDID>studyUID>2.25.143966910120672170538921915162328371094</studyUID><studyUIDID>251</studyUIDID></study><study recNO="1" seriesRecCount="1">      <patientID>123456</patientID><accessionNumber>M120170428105233</accessionNumber><patientIDID>35</patientIDID><studyUID>2.25.303229748643803883750255516818503774905</studyUID>      <studyUIDID>252</studyUIDID></study></dataset>');

function getStudyUIDByAccessionNumber (access) {
    for (var study of a.find('study')) {
        var accessionNumber = study.getElementsByTagName('accessionNumber')[0].innerHTML;
        if ( accessionNumber == access) {
            return (study.getElementsByTagName('studyUID')[0].innerHTML);
        }
    }}

getStudyUIDByAccessionNumber('M120170428105233');
```